# I am using bootstrap to create a page and found a Navbar code. What do we use "(current)" in the below code for?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me <span class="sr-only"></span>(current)</span></a>
```

I trying to understand the use of "(current)" in the above code.

Comment: It acts as text.

Answer (score 1):

The code you appear to be referencing comes from [this GetBootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/navbar-fixed-top/).

This `(current)` is merely text that gets rendered inside of the `<span>`, which has the class `sr-only`. The [`sr-only` Bootstrap class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/screenreaders/) is used to denote the current page that a user is on when they view the page on a screen reader. It's designed to assist those who are visually impaired, and will not be rendered for users who are not using screen readers.